# Regex expression to put "." after sixth position from right in HQL

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hql, impala

I have an requirement to put a dot(.) after 6th character from right to left. The total character length is 15 char.

I have below table:

```
Tab1
---
Col1    Col2
---    -----
1      000000000000098
2      000000000000234
5      000000000024556
6      000000012345677
7      000000013ABC686
```

Expected Output:
Column value should be right adjusted to 6 places after decimal

```
Col1  Col2
---   ----
1     0.000098
2     0.000234
5     0.024556
6    12.345677
7    13.ABC686
```

Tried so far in SQL and its **working** assuming max length of number is 15 char, I am putting "." after 9th Char.

```
Select
  col
 ,regexp_replace(col,'^([[:digit:]]{9})','\1.') as res
From
tab;
```

But same **doesnt** work in `HQL`.

Result getting in HQL: It always adds 1 instead of taking rest if the char

```
Col1  Col2
    ---   ----
    1     1.000098
    2     1.000234
    5     1.024556
    6     1.345677
```

Comment: Are you using Hive, Oracle, or some other database?  This is not clear.

Comment: Using `Hive`..Same is  in my question as well.HQL- Hive query lang

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your data requirement correctly, you can simply divide the `Col2` values by one million here, after converting the `Col2` values from strings to integers.

```sql
SELECT Col1, CAST(Col2 AS int) / 1000000.0 AS Col2
FROM tab;
```

To add the decimal place to the strings, without using actual division, we can try:

```sql
SELECT Col1,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(Col2, '(.{6})$', '.$1') AS Col2
FROM tab;
```

Comment: Can we do it by regex ? Since character can be Alphanumeric as well, Edited question

Comment: ...maybe, but I see no reason to do division with regex.  If you want a text result, just cast the output from my answer to `varchar` go from there.

Comment: `000000013ABC686` division gives error in this case

Comment: Check the updated answer for something which might work for you.

Comment: Not getting correct result in HQL. Not sure if you checked in Oracle. Getting `000000.1`

Comment: @VnS The first capture group in Hive appears to be `$1`, not `\1`.  I only copied from your question, assuming you had the syntax right.

Comment: @Thanks Tim.. Regex not working but Let me se some other way,